# Location of logon script in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to modify a logon script that was created by a previous employee.
When I look in Active Directory Users & Computers - in the profile tab - it says Logon Script: Logon.bat

But where is that logon.bat? how can i find the path to this file?

Also, is there any way i can bulk change every users logon script location?

Comment: I'd suggest submitting the bulk change as a separate question.  You'll be more likely to get attention to it and it'll be easier to find later in life by someone searching for that same question.

Comment: I find the tricky part to be remembering if the file is logon.bat or login.bat when I specify it in the Properties :-P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look in \\myDomain.loc\NETLOGON\

If this is where your predecessor stored the script, you can find the location of this folder locally to the DC by opening the Computer Management console on the DC, and checking through the Shares (you'll find the path to the Netlogon share here).

As for bulk changes, in AD Users and Computers you can <kbd>shift</kbd> select multiple users, right click, and choose Properties.  Go to the Profile tab, and change the Logon Script.

Comment: yep, what he said. Often it's \\DC1\netlogon or \\companyname-DC1\netlogon

Comment: +1, but you should also consider using GPO logon scripts as they will remove a LOT of this pain from the whole experience.  The per-user "logon script" property is only provided for legacy NT4 backwards compatibility.